# How to Restrict adding a new item to SharePoint 2010 list if the existing item falls in the same time range

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list with 4 columns namely `Region Name` (dropdown choices), `Start Time` (Date & Time), `End Time` (Date & Time) and `Comments` (multiple line text).

It allows users to book a region for a particular time frame i.e. using start time and end time.

I want to put a validation such that if user A has selected Region1 for some time period the other user say B should not be able to select the same region if start and end time coincides.

Comment: You should include some code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: I am just trying to achieve above through OOB feature, Infopath forms. I m no expert on coding but if there is any help on code I can have a sandboxed solution developed for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Infopath form I think the only way is to use custom code.

Usually for shared resources like your Regions, in sharepoint 2010, calendars are used.
There is a feature to check if a resource is already used, but you can register for a resource already selected if you want to.

Maybe using a custom calendar would be your solution ?

Comment: So you mean I should change my approach. Rather than using Custom List I should go for a Calender list to achieve my requirements ?

Comment: I don't know if you can quit about infopath because I don't know about your requirements. But using the calendar may be an option you should consider. You can try it and see if you can find a compromise. Otherwise  you will have to use custom code solution.

Answer (score 0):

For InfoPath, I can think of this workaround.

For example, a user already selected Region 1 7:00-8:00AM, user B should cannot choose/submit this schedule. What you can do is pass the values (Region and Start/End time) to the list data connection. Then it will query the list. If it found a match, set an action that will pass a value (like ID) to a hidden textbox. This means that someone already submitted this schedule. Then show an error/textbox message and disable the submit button. If the query returns null, then show a Ok message.

You can use a button "check if available" to trigger this query or put this on submit button. I suggest the check button so the user can modify the schedule before submitting.

Comment: how to pass  the values (Region and Start/End time) to the list data connection ? Didn't get you

Comment: for example, put an action rule on a the dropdown (Region) then set the field(Region) under queryFields folder of the Data Connection that you wanted to query. After the set field action, add the Query the data connection to get the result based on the values that you set under queryFields

Comment: I have done what you suggested above. Earlier you adviced that... If it found a match, set an action that will pass a value (like ID) to a hidden textbox. This means that someone already submitted this schedule. Then show an error/textbox message and disable the submit button. If the query returns null, then show a Ok message.

How to achive this ?

Comment: try putting a default value on to the hidden box. try 0 as default value. Then when you get a null value, it will pass nothing at will set it to blank. Your OK message will show when it is blank. The two messages will not show at the beginning because of 0 value. For error message, try showing it when ID>0.

Then, put a rule at the beginning of the actions (before setting the queryFields) that when when clicked it will set the hidden box to 0. This will refresh the checker/hidden box before getting any values to let the user use the checker multiple times.