# How to validate new items a user tries to add to list using form against the existing items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have a list that allow user to book an application in particular test region against himself for certain time slot.
For this there are below 5 Fields in my SharePoint List

```
Application_Name (dropdown)   Test_Region (dropdown)  Start_Time  End_Time  Booked_By
```

Suppose the above fields contains following list items respectively

```
App_1         Region_1     9:00 AM Monday    11:00 AM Monday   User_1
```

I want to set up a validation that allow user to enter new item through form :

1. If If other user selects same app name (App_1) but different region (Region_2) then he must be able to submit the form only if he selects Start_Time > 11:00 AM Monday or End_Time < 9:00 AM Monday.
2. If other user selects same app name (App_1) and region (Region_1) then he must be able to submit the form without any issue.
3. If any other user select different app (App_3) and any region (Region_1/Region_2/Region_3) he must be able to submit without any issues provided similar combination doesn't exist in the list. And if it does it must satisfy either of above two condition.

If the condition does not satisfy the current requester must be prompted that "This app is already in use in other region by x user. Please select a different time slot."

I hope the requirement is clear. Please share your expertise thoughts on this.
Currently I am looking to achieve this using InfoPath form but didn't find a luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this is a duplicate with this

[How to Restrict adding a new item to SharePoint 2010 list if the existing item falls in the same time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307070/how-to-restrict-adding-a-new-item-to-sharepoint-2010-list-if-the-existing-item-f/31334870#31334870)

see my answer on that link

Comment: yes.. u may say duplicate. I just tried to make the requirements more clear.